# Запуск команды в командной строке windows через php без ожидания ответа

Tags: windows, cmd, php

Запускаю следующую команду через *shell_exec*

```
C:\wamp\bin\ffmpeg\bin>start /b ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -b:v 600k -maxrate 600k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=854:480 -threads 0 -codec:a   libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k output2.mp4 <NUL >NUL 2>NUL
```

Скрипт всё равно ждет... Ограничение shell_exec() вроде учел, что нужно выводить stdou и stderr куда-либо, чтобы можно было оставить команду в "фоне" и не ждать конца её выполнения. При этом запуская это через командную строку напрямую, вроде конвертация идет в "фоне", то есть нет вывода, а команда все ровно выполняется.
Есть у кого идеи по этому поводу?

**UPD**

```
$cmd = 'START /D C:\wamp\bin\ffmpeg\bin\ /B CMD /C ffmpeg -y -i ' . $content['upload_data']['full_path'] . ' -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -b:v 600k -maxrate 600k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=854:480 -threads 0 -codec:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k ' .  $content['upload_data']['file_path'] . $content['upload_data']['raw_name'] . '.480' . $content['upload_data']['file_ext'] . ' <NUL >NUL 2>NUL';

exec($cmd);
```

Вот команда в php. Смена *shell_exec* на *exec* так же не помогла.

Comment: @Johny спасибо. popen помогло. Единственное хотел бы спросить, почему popen работает, а exec и т.д. нет, ведь и exec тоже позволяет выполнять команды в фоне. Так же добавьте пожалуйста ответ, я его приму. Наверное по "Opens a pipe to a process executed by **forking** the command given by command"  этой причине?

Comment: Да, по этому. Просто у этих функций назначение разное: `exec()` и ей подобные нужны, чтобы выполнить команду, получить ответ и передать дальше в код, в то время, как `proc_open()` и ей подобные представляют некое подобие терминала, что ли )) Они запускают программу отдельным потоком и дальше могут с этой программой "взаимодействовать"

Почему не работает `exec` так, как ожидается - не отвечу. Сам когда-то с этим столкнулся, не поборол, нашел другое решение - и все :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было бы здорово сам кусок кода php увидеть в том виде, в котором вы эту команду вызываете.

Такое перенапраление потоков, как у вас, на сколько я помню, срабатывает только в `system()` и `exec()`.

Если же это не приносит должный результат, попробуйте использовать `popen()`

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не нужно знать результат выполнения внешней программы то вы можете каждый exec отправлять в отдельную нить (thread) http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php и одновременно на выполнение можете отправить сколько хочешь команд (все они будут выполнятся асинхронно) , потолок тут только максимальное возможное кол-во процессов в системе , если это облако то и об этом можно не думать . Если вам нужны результаты выполненных команд то можете их кэшить куданить типа REDIS . Вообще для асинхронных операций для php есть хорошая штука http://daemon.io/ .

да еще 1 момент прям с оф сайта :

> Замечание:
>   Если вы собираетесь использовать эту функцию в программе, работающей в качестве демона, убедитесь, что стандартный вывод функции направлен в файл или другой поток, в противном случае PHP зависнет вплоть до конца выполнения программы.